# Composer is not autoloading my autoloader class

Tags: php, composer-php, swagger, autoload

So, I've recently included a private package in my composer.json file and is working fine. It cloned the project of my BitBucket repository as I wanted. However, I'm having an issue with the autoloading of the classes of the package.

If I add the autoloader, manually, in a controller of my Silex project, it works great.

```
require_once('/var/www/vendor/my-vendor/my-private-package/autoload.php');
```

However, if I don't add the autoload.php class, then I get an error of class not found:

```
18/02/07 17:05:33 [error] 1174#0: *1187 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Swagger\Client\Api\MyPHPClientApi' not found in /vagrant/public/personal-project/src/App/Frontal/Controller/MyController.php:88
Stack trace:
#0 /vagrant/public/personal-project/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(151): App\Frontal\Controller\SleepingPlaceController->showList()
#1 /vagrant/public/personal-project/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1)
#2 /vagrant/public/personal-project/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Application.php(496): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#3 /vagrant/public/personal-project/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Application.php(477): Silex\Application->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#4 /vagrant/public/personal-project/web/index.php(10): Silex\Application->run()
#5 {main}
```

So what am I doing wrong?

The composer.json of my private package looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "my-vendor/my-private-package",
    "description": "",
    "keywords": [
        "swagger",
        "php",
        "sdk",
        "api"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://swagger.io",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Swagger and contributors",
            "homepage": "https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-mbstring": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.8",
        "satooshi/php-coveralls": "~1.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~2.6",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~1.12"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "Swagger\\Client\\" : "lib/" }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": { "Swagger\\Client\\" : "test/" }
    }
}
```

The classes in the private package are under the lib/ subdirectory.

By the way, this client was auto-generated by the Swagger Editor online tool https://editor.swagger.io/

Comment: Are you including the composer autoloader in your code?

Comment: Yes @MarkBaker, and the rest of the packages, like Twig, Doctrine, Silex, etc, are working perfectly OK.

Comment: Removing Silex tag as this is not a Silex related question. Also, keep in mind that [Silex has an official EOL date (june 2018)](http://symfony.com/blog/the-end-of-silex), you should think about moving to SF4 ([there is an open issue on the need to create a howto guide](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/8678))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding your root name space in your composer here:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": { "Swagger\\Client\\" : "lib/" }
}
```

Notice your error: `Uncaught Error: Class 'Swagger\Client\Api\MyPHPClientApi' not found`

Composer installs your dependencies in your `vendor` folder but you are telling it to find the `Swagger\Client\` namespace in your `lib` folder.

Assuming that your private repo follows PSR-4 (which is safe to assume since you're using a PSR-4 autoloader), you just need to remove this line in your composer and [generate again the composer autoloader](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-) (`composer dump-autoloader`).

Comment: Wow! That was sort of what it was happening. The thing is that other packages, like Silex main package, or Twig, have that autoload section as well. What they don't have is an autoload.php in the source directory of their root folders. So what was causing the issue was the autoload.php. When I removed it, everything worked fine.